# Scala: convenient binding of collection type parameters

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For convenience, clarity, and abstraction, I want to make up another name for a specific binding of a parameterized collection trait. For instance, first consider:

```
import collection.mutable.Map // NB: Map is a trait
val m1 = Map[String, Int]()   // uses the Map companion object to create a HashMap
```

Now I want to substitute `MyMap` for `Map[String, Int]`. Ideally I would just like to do something like:

```
trait MyMap extends Map[String, Int]
object MyMap extends Map[String, Int]   // not good enough by itself, need some apply defs
val m2 = MyMap()                        // nope
```

I could add more stuff to the `MyMap` companion object, or I could make MyMap extend `HashMap[String, Int]` and forget about relying on the magic defaulting inside the Map companion object.

But those alternatives seem like too much work for something that should be simple: I just want `MyMap` to act like `Map[String, Int]` wherever it appears. What's the easiest way to do that, or am I missing some deeper principle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a type alias:

```
type MyMap = Map[String, Int]
```

Note this won't give you `object MyMap`, and if you define it, it is *not* the companion object (`object Map` is) and the compiler won't check it for implicit conversions.

Comment: You can get easy access to the factory method (i.e. apply(..)) with `val MyMap = Map.apply[String, Int] _` but, again, that's not the companion object, just a single function.

Comment: `val MyMap = Map` will give you the companion.

Comment: `val MyMap = Map` does not give me a companion for `Map[String, Int]`, though, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey Romanov
A type alias won't give you the factory method. An import on the other hand will.

```
scala> import collection.mutable.{Map => MyMap}
scala> val m1 = MyMap()
m1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Nothing, Nothing] = Map()
```

Comment: Um, but the import makes `MyMap` be another name for `Map`, not `Map[String, Int]`, as I would like.